# Cómo puedo solucionar este problema?

Tags: android-studio, flutter, dart, sdk

****Hola estimados,**

**[image: Soy nuevo en esto y ya he intento de varias formas pero no logro solucionarlo.**]**

Resolving dependencies...
The current Dart SDK version is 3.3.1.

Because crud depends on http >=0.2.8+2 <0.13.0-nullsafety.0 which doesn't support null safety, version solving failed.

The lower bound of "sdk: '<2.0.0 or >=2.0.0-dev.61.0 <3.0.0'" must be 2.12.0 or higher to enable null safety.
For details, see https://dart.dev/null-safety

You can try the following suggestion to make the pubspec resolve:

- Try upgrading your constraint on http: flutter pub add http:^1.2.0

**Saludos**

Comment: _Try upgrading your constraint on http: flutter pub add http:^1.2.0_.

Comment: Bienvenido a Stackoverflow en *Español*, por favor traduce tu pregunta para brindarte ayudarte.

Comment: @DavElsanto, el compi no ha hablado en inglés, ha referenciado la última parte del mensaje del op.